# How can I attach a vertical scrollbar to a treeview using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have been trying to attach a horizontal and vertical scrollbar for the tkinter treeview. In my main application all the data comes from a sql database so I need to be able to scroll through lots of data within a sperate window. I have managed to place the treeview within the child window, however I am still stuck on how to attach scrollbars that work.

Although there is a vertical scrollbar at the moment it doesn't seem to be attached to the treeview and does not scroll through any data that I input.

Is there a way of putting vertical and horizontal scrollbars within my application?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
import sys
import re
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont


class application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.frames = {}        

            for F in (app_one, app_two):
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[F] = frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(app_one)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class app_one(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(app_two))
            button.pack()


class app_two(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.msgText = tk.StringVar()
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Open", command= self.Child_Window)
        button.pack()

    def Child_Window(self):
        win2 = Toplevel()
        new_element_header=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th']
        treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(win2)
        treeScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        tree = ttk.Treeview(win2,columns=new_element_header, show="headings", yscrollcommand = treeScroll)
        tree.heading("1st", text="1st")
        tree.heading("2nd", text="2nd")
        tree.heading("3rd", text="3rd")
        tree.heading("4th", text="4th")
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 2", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 3", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 4", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 5", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 6", values=("1A","1b"))
        tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 7", values=("1A","1b"))

        tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        treeScroll.config(command=tree.yview)


app = application()
app.wm_geometry("420x200")
app.wm_title("Test")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You connect scrollbars to a `Treeview` widget the same as you do for any other scrollable widget.

In the case of a vertical scrollbar, the `yscrollcommand` attribute of the widget needs to be set to the `set` function of the scrollbar (or something that works just like it). Also, the `command` attribute of the scrollbar needs to be set to the `yview` method of the tree (or something that works just like it)

For example:

```
treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(...)
tree = ttk.Treeview(...)

treeScroll.configure(command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=treeScroll.set)
```

Configuring a horizontal scrollbar is similar, though of course it needs to be tied to the `xview` method rather than the `yview` method of the tree.

Comment: @WhyWhat: you're going to have to be more specific. This is precisely how to attach a scrollbar to a treeview widget. It has worked for people for over a decade.