# Focus on ttk.Treeview widget

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a treeview widget with a vertical scrollbar and I want a scrollbar to be active (to use it with a mouse scroll) as i hover mouse pointer above the treeview widget. Is it possible to do in some way? I've done this easily for Text widgets by using 
`widget.bind("<Enter>", widget_focus_callback)`
but ttk.Treeview has different functionality for focus() method.

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. I am looking into a ttk Treeview and it always scrolls when the mouse is over it. Do you really mean above, that is outside the Treeview widget, mouse over another widget?

Comment: @progmatico in my case treeview is scrollable only if some of its items is selected. Hovering with mouse above it doesn't allow to scroll it, at least on python 2.7 and windows 7/10 x64 if it's important

Comment: Are you doing this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375489/how-can-i-attach-a-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollbar-to-a-treeview-using-tkinter

Comment: @progmatico, yes, exactly the same, and scrollbar itself works, but only when i click on some of tree's elements