# Nesting a Tkinter treeview widget inside a ScrolledText widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

So I'm copying and pasting an old scrolledtext widget from an old program I wrote, and trying to merge it with some treeview code I just discovered.
So far haven't been able to get them to work.

I'm just wanting the treeview to be directly inside the space just under the wallet tab, with the possibility of adding completely different treeviews under the other tabs.

I tried adding "txt1." before all the tree lines, but it just said txt1 does not have the attribute tree.

input

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1180x1023")
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Wallet')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Inventory Quantity')
tab_control.add(tab3, text='Inventory Alphabetical')
txt1 = (ScrolledText(tab1))
tree["columns"]=("date","location", "quantity", "credit")
tree.heading("#0", text="Name")
tree.heading("date", text="Date")
tree.heading("location", text="Location")
tree.heading("quantity", text="Quantity")
tree.heading("credit", text="Credit")
tree.column("#0",minwidth=0,width=180, stretch=YES)
tree.column("date",minwidth=0,width=80, stretch=YES)
tree.column("location",minwidth=0,width=80, stretch=YES)
tree.column("quantity",minwidth=0,width=80, stretch=YES)
tree.column("credit",minwidth=0,width=80, stretch=YES)

tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A","1b"))
tree.insert("" , 1,    text="Line 2", values=("1A","1b", "blah"))
tree.insert("" , 2,    text="Line 3", values=("1A","1b", "blah2", "the return of the blah"))

id1 = tree.insert("", 3, "dir1", text="A")
tree.insert(id1, "end", "dir 1", text="beginning with A", values=("2A","2B"))
id2 = tree.insert("", 4, "dir2", text="B")
tree.insert(id2, "end", "dir 2", text="beginning with B", values=("3B","3C", "firefly"))
id3 = tree.insert("", 5, "dir3", text="C")
tree.insert(id3, "end", "dir 3", text="beginning with C", values=("4Z","JF"))

txt2 = (ScrolledText(tab2))
txt3 = (ScrolledText(tab3))
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

screenshot
[image: Screenshot of Tkinter]

Comment: `scrolledtext` is a widget intended to deal with multi-line text strings. This is not really the kind of data managed by `treeview`. Why don't you put your `treeview` widget into a scrollable Frame?

Comment: Happy to give that a go, can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I attach a horizontal and vertical scrollbar to a treeview using Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375489/how-can-i-attach-a-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollbar-to-a-treeview-using-tkinter)